# How to write a MySQL query with WHERE in json

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

So I have a value saved in MySQL DB that's in the following format:
`[["88"],["90"],["91"]]`

How could I write the query to be something like

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE jsonColumn IN '88'` and it would find all the entries where in JSON data there is `88` ?

Comment: hey @Xeen I afriad `[["88"],["90"],["91"]]` is not a valid JSON

Comment: You should change your table design. Never store multiple values in a single column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better looking for `["88"]` using `WHERE`:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `jsonColumn` LIKE '%["88"]%'
```

This will ensure that when searching for `88`, values such as `["188"]` are not incorrectly returned. Also, are you sure you need EVERYTHING from the table? Generally, `SELECT *` is not needed.

That having been said, it may be better to optimise your normalization so you're not storing JSON or serialized data. This will make your queries much more efficient and generally easier to work with, especially for more complex queries.

Comment: I'd like to know also why a downvote. This is a good answer and has relevant explanation.

Comment: @juergend I was genuinely interested to hear why someone thought it warranted a downvote. It wasn't an attack or act of petulance, I wondered if I'd missed something. What's wrong in asking someone to explain their downvote, so that not only I, but also the OP can learn what makes this answer good / bad.